Arize-phoenix: Unable to load query_df when trying to perform eval using Arize-Phoenix with langchain
I am trying to use arize-phoenix to perform eval on my langchain RAG pipeline however the get_qa_with_reference(px.Client()) function always returns None. Below is the code
queries_df = get_qa_with_reference(px.Client())
retrieved_documents_df = get_retrieved_documents(px.Client())
spans_df = px.Client().get_spans_dataframe()

run_eval(queries_df, retrieved_documents_df)

def run_eval(queries_df, retrieved_documents_df):
    eval_model = LiteLLMModel(model='ollama/llama3')
    
    hallucination_evaluator = HallucinationEvaluator(eval_model)
    qa_correctness_evaluator = QAEvaluator(eval_model)
    relevance_evaluator = RelevanceEvaluator(eval_model)
    
    hallucination_eval_df, qa_correctness_eval_df = run_evals(
        dataframe=queries_df,
        evaluators=[hallucination_evaluator, qa_correctness_evaluator],
        provide_explanation=True,
    )

    relevance_eval_df = run_evals(
        dataframe=retrieved_documents_df,
        evaluators=[relevance_evaluator],
        provide_explanation=True,
    )[0]

    px.Client().log_evaluations(
        SpanEvaluations(eval_name="Hallucination", dataframe=hallucination_eval_df),
        SpanEvaluations(eval_name="QA Correctness", dataframe=qa_correctness_eval_df),
        DocumentEvaluations(eval_name="Relevance", dataframe=relevance_eval_df),
    )

When printing the query_df it is always None and output shows No Spans Found despite there being spans in the arize UI. retrieved_documents_df seems to work fine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\RAGS\main.py", line 58, in <module>
    run_eval(queries_df, retrieved_documents_df)
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\RAGS\main.py", line 24, in run_eval
    hallucination_eval_df, qa_correctness_eval_df = run_evals(
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\phoenix\evals\classify.py", line 354, in run_evals
    total_records = len(dataframe)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

